# Trying to add column to data_frame by using flask html dropdown select list

Tags: python, pandas, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to add column of drop down select list to data frame before storing to mysql in FLASK, SQLAlchemy, Python. Can you help plz. Getting error:

`TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Following are two files used for project. app.py and view_two.html. Basically, I am developing application to submit all bank statement excel file to mysql. First I use PANDAS to view data frame by converting df to dictionary. Now before sending to mysql I would like to assign categories to each transaction whether it is cleaning expense, bank fees, food expense etc..

app.py

```
@app.route('/submit_two', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit_two():
    category = (request.form.get['category'])
    a_two = session.get('a_two')
    df = pd.DataFrame(a_two)
    df['Categories'] = category
    new_data_two = df.to_dict(orient='record')
    a_two = new_data_two

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # df.fillna(0)
        # a_two.fillna(0)
        for data in a_two:
            fav_two = BankData(process_date=data.get('Process date'), description=data.get(
                'Description'), debit=data.get('Debit'), credit=data.get('Credit'), balance=data.get('Balance'), category=data.get('Categories'))
            db.session.add(fav_two)
            db.session.commit()

        print("Bank data submitted")
        return render_template("index.html")
```

view_two.html

```
<body>
    <!-- First Containter Starts -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col md-12">
                <div class="jumbotron p-3">
                    <!-- table header -->

                    <!-- Data view Table Starts  -->
                    <form action="{{url_for('submit_two')}}" method="POST">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
                            {% if new_data_two %}

                            <tr>

                                {% for key in new_data_two[0] %}
                                <th> {{ key }} </th>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </tr>
                            {% endif %}

                            <!-- table rows -->
                            {% for dict_item in new_data_two %}
                            <tr>
                                {% for value in dict_item.values() %}
                                <td> {{ value }} </td>

                                {% endfor %}
                                <td>
                                    <!-- <form action="{{url_for('submit_two')}}" method="POST"> -->
                                    <select id="category" name="category">
                                        <option value="bankFees">Bank Fees</option>
                                        <option value="cleaning">Cleaning</option>
                                        <option value="sundry">Sundry</option>
                                        <option value="telephone">Telephone</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <!-- </form> -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </table>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right btn-lg"
                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{url_for('submit_two')}}">Submit Bank Data</button>
                    </form>


                    <!-- Data View Table Ends -->

                    <!-- <div class="modal-body"> -->
                    <!-- <div class="jumbotron p-3"> -->

                    <!-- <form action="{{url_for('submit_two')}}" method="POST"> -->



                    <!-- <table> -->
                    <!-- <th> -->
                    <!-- <label> -->
                    <!-- <h2>Submit Bank data</h2> -->
                    <!-- </label> -->
                    <!-- <input type="file" class="form-control" name="myfile" required="1"> -->
                    <!-- </th> -->



                    <!-- <th> -->

                    <!-- <h2> -->
                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" -->
                    <!-- class="btn btn-success float-right btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" -->
                    <!-- data-target="{{url_for('submit_two')}}">Submit Bank Data</button> -->
                    <!-- </h2> -->
                    <!-- </th> -->

                    <!-- </table> -->



                    <!-- </form> -->

                </div>
            </div>




        </div>

        {%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line: 
`category = (request.form.get['category'])`

Should be: `category = (request.form.get('category'))`

Comment: ```AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'translate'```